# Angular - Home component

Tags: angular, components

Getting this error message:

```
'GlobalDataSummary' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
An element access expression should take an argument.
Property 'forEach' does not exist on type 'GlobalDataSummary'.
Parameter 'cs' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

Need help!

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataServiceService } from '../../services/data-service.service';
import { GlobalDataSummary } from '../../models/gloabl-data';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  totalConfirmed = 0;
  totalActive = 0;
  totalDeaths = 0;
  totalRecovered = 0;
  globalData = GlobalDataSummary[];
  constructor(private dataService : DataServiceService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dataService.getGlobalData()
    .subscribe(
      {
        next : (result)=>{
          console.log(result);
          this.globalData = result;
          result.forEach(cs=>{
            if(!Number.isNaN(cs.confirmed)){
              this.totalActive+=cs.active
            this.totalConfirmed+=cs.confirmed
            this.totalDeaths+=cs.deaths
            this.totalRecovered+=cs.recovered
            }
            
          })
        }
      }
    )

  }

}
```

Comment: Please show the code for `models/gloabl-data` and `services/data-service.service`.

Answer (score 0):

With this line:

```
globalData = GlobalDataSummary[];
```

you're trying to assign a type (`GlobalDataSummary[]`, which means an array whose elements are of type `GlobalDataSummary`) to a variable. That is not possible and that's what the Typescript compiler is claiming about: you can only assign a value to a variable and here you're using a type as a value.

You can use this syntax to initialize `globalData` as an empty array:

```
globalData: GlobalDataSummary[] = [];
```